# Disable particular item in the ListBox

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7.1

I bind list of objects to my ListBox in WindowsPhone application. This business object has one boolean property. Based on the Boolean property i need to set the IsEnabled property in the ListBoxItem.

Is there any way to achieve this in WindowsPhone ListBox ?

Answer (score 1):

There're few ways to achieve this:

1. You can add the ListBoxItem by C# code and set the property properly.
2. In Xaml, inside the list box, place the following:

`<ListBox.Resources>`
    `<Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">`
       `<Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding Content.IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>`
    `</Style>`
`</ListBox.Resources>`

Here I assume that the property name in your model object is IsEnabled, change it according to its real name.